# Looking for the name of a video game involving spells and wolves

Tags: story-identification

I couple years ago my friend let me play a game on his Nintendo DS and I remember playing a man with a sword running around in a misty maze of trenches that lead into open arenas where you fight wolves. I also remember using some kind of spells by using the stylus to trace symbols. I cannot remember the name of it and that's about all that I remember about it.

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like it could be Lost Magic. For most of the game you commanded a small team of monsters while controlling your MC, but in some of the earlier parts you didn't have them yet. There were definitely levels with trenches and wolves, and you cast spells by tracing a combination of runes on the bottom screen.

Gameplay video: